# In Clojure, is it possible to define an anonymous function within an anonymous function?

Tags: clojure, anonymous-function

For example, solving the following problem

http://projecteuler.net/problem=5

I came up with the following solution

```
(defn div [n] (= 0 (reduce + (map #(mod n %) (range 1 21)))))
(take 1 (filter #(= true (div %)) (range 20 1e11 20)))
```

Suppose for some golfing fun I wish to merge the first line as an anonymous function into the second line.  Does the language support this?

Comment: You could rewrite your solution in a more effective way. See my answer below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes it does, but you cannot nest the `#()` reader-macro forms, you have to use the `(fn)` form.

For example:

```
(#(#(+ %1 %2) 1) 2)
```

does not work, because there's no way to refer to the arguments of the outer anonymous functions. This is read as the outer function taking two arguments and the inner function taking zero arguments.

But you can write the same thing with `(fn...)`s:

```
user=> (((fn [x] (fn [y] (+ x y))) 1) 2)
3
```

You can also use the `#()` form for one of the two anonymous functions, e.g:

```
user=> (#((fn [x] (+ x %)) 1) 2)
3
```

So you can inline your `div` function like this (notice that we had to change the `#()` form passed to `map` to a `(fn)` form):

```
#(= true (= 0 (reduce + (map (fn [x] (mod % x)) (range 1 21)))))
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb: `fn` is the syntax to define an anonymous function, not `#()`. `#()` is only a convenience for simple function calls like `#(mod % x)` where `fn` would add a lot of noise. For functions with a longer body `fn` should be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite your solution in a much simpler and more efficient way (x2 faster!)

```
(defn div [n] (every? #(= 0 (mod n %)) (range 1 21)))
(take 1 (filter div (range 20 1e11 20)))
```

The reason it is more efficient is because `every?` wouldn't traverse the whole list but rather stop when one of the element of the list is false.

Comment: Or you could solve it about 10⁶ times faster by avoiding brute force entirely . . .

Comment: Indeed. But I was considering any `clojure` related improvements not mathematical ones.